# Why would you remap the tf topic?

Tags: ros, remap, topic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen some code that looks like this:

```
 <node name="jointState2tf"
         pkg="robot_state_publisher"
         type="robot_state_publisher">
     <remap from="tf" to="hand/tf"/>
     <remap from="joint_states" to="hand/joint_states"/>
   </node>
```

Why would one remap the `/tf` topic to something else (in this case, `hand/tf`)? Shouldn't all Transform messages go on the `/tf` topic anyways?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237034/why-would-you-remap-the-tf-topic?/) by [Felix Duvallet](https://answers.ros.org/users/22253/felix-duvallet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2016-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One use case I know of (apparently not the one you're referencing): you want to simulate the effects of commands without actually moving the robot. That is, you maintain two sets of tf information, one for the actual robot and one for the sim-robot, syncing them occasionally.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3